# Left-looking Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, computational-mathematics, gaussian-elimination

I read about left-looking Gaussian elimination which is a variant of Gaussian elimination we use (called right-looking Gaussian elimination) but I could not understand it.
Could any one give me an example about it. This is an example of $3\times 3$ Gaussian elimination we use (right-looking because we are always modifying the bottom lower portion which is to the right of the pivot).
\begin{equation} \label{guass1}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}   \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_{1}\\x_{2} \\x_{3} \\\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}b_{1}\\b_{2} \\b_{3} \\\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation} \label{guass2}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & a_{22}^{(2)} & a_{23}^{(2)}  \\
0 & a_{32}^{(2)} & a_{33}^{(2)}   \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_{1}\\x_{2} \\x_{3} \\\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}b_{1}\\b_{2}^{(2)} \\b_{3}^{(2)} \\\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{gauss3}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & a_{22}^{(2)} & a_{23}^{(2)}  \\
0 & 0 & a_{33}^{(3)}   \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_{1}\\x_{2} \\x_{3} \\\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}b_{1}\\b_{2}^{(2)} \\b_{3}^{(3)} \\\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
For the left-looking variant, I am quoting this from a reference,

> delay the updates for $a_{ij}$ until column j is about to be pivotal, that is,
>    \begin{equation}\label{gauss4}
>  a_{ij}^{(j)}  =   a_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} l_{ik}u_{kj}  
>  \end{equation}
>   The entries $l_{ik}$ are to the left of $a_{ij}$ in the matrix pattern, so this form is called left-looking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how from the formula 
 \begin{equation} 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
u_{11} & a_{12}^{(2)} & a_{13} \\
l_{21} & a_{22}^{(2)} & a_{23}  \\
l_{31} & a_{32}^{(2)} & a_{33}   \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_{1}\\x_{2} \\x_{3} \\\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}b_{1}\\b_{2} \\b_{3}\\\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{12} = a_{12}^{(2)} = a_{12} \quad,\quad  a_{22}^{(2)}  =   a_{22} - l_{21} u_{12} & , & a_{32}^{(2)} = a_{32} - l_{31}u_{12}\\
 \end{eqnarray*}
In the next step, we modify the third column 
\begin{equation} 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
u_{11} & u_{12} & a_{13}^{(3)} \\
l_{21} & u_{22} & a_{23}^{(3)}  \\
l_{31} & l_{32} & a_{33}^{(3)}   \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_{1}\\x_{2} \\x_{3} \\\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}b_{1}\\b_{2} \\b_{3}\\\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{13}^{(3)} = u_{13}  =   a_{13} & , & a_{23}^{(3)}  =   a_{23} - l_{21}u_{13} \quad,\quad a_{33}^{(3)} = a_{33} - l_{31}u_{13} - l_{32}u_{23}\\
 \end{eqnarray*}
which yields the same results as the previous example.